# Как организовать файлы проекта в отдельные папки Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Доброго вечера!
Имеется проект, в котором довольно много классов, интерфейсов, форм и т.п:

[image: Обозреватель решений.]

Вопрос в чем, как мне эти классы и другое поместить в папки, например формы в папку "Forms" и т.д?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Solution Explorer (Обозревателе решений) вы можете создать новые папки в проекте.

Для этого используйте контекстное меню проекта, кликнув правой кнопкой мыши на имени проекта. В появившемся меню выберите Add -> New Folder.

Если у вас стоит Resharper, то переносить удобнее при помощи рефакторинга Move To Folder - он автоматически откорректирует неймспейсы и include'ы, не нужно будет руками поправлять.

Собственно, на что обратите внимание, если у вас установлен Resharper и вы решили переносить классы по папкам. В свойствах папки (Alt+Enter на имени папки или в контекстном меню пункт Properties) при установленном решарпере можно увидеть параметр `NameSpaceProvider`, который по умолчанию ставится в True.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если класс создаётся в папке с `NameSpaceProvider` = True, то к имени неймспейса будет добавляться имя этой папки, если False -- то не будет.

Соответственно, если вы просто перенёсете файл из корня проекта в папку FolderName, то решарпер будет подсвечивать как ошибку неймспейс (он останется старым -- ProjectName), правильный неймспейс будет ProjectName.FolderName.

Соответственно, вы можете как поправить неймспейс (ручками или через магическое Alt+Enter решарпера), либо проставить `NameSpaceProvider` = False, либо переносить при помощи рефакторинга.

Ну и в случае, если расставляете на папках `NameSpaceProvider` = False то не забывайте добавлять в версионный контроль (TFS/git) файлы.DotSettings (у каждого проекта в солюшине свой), в нём [решарпер хранит настройки для NameSpaceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6821579/5752652).

Answer (score 4):

Добавить папку -> правой кнопкой мыши по проекту (не по решению), добавить -> новая папка.

А файлы можно потом перетащить мышью.